# Mesh hair with lattice does not collide with other mesh

Tags: mesh, collision, soft-body, lattice

I'm using Blender 2.93.1

I have made hair with curves and turned them into mesh. Then I followed the video "How to Animate Stylized Hair Using Soft Body Physics in Blender in 2 Minutes" (https://youtu.be/rMU_fa1G-bA) (adding lattice, adding a vertex group for lattice, parenting it to head bone).

But at around 1:36 there I added collision and outer thickness to my body mesh, but mesh which is meant to be hair still comes through body mesh

How cam I make the meshes collide?

[image]

Link to the file
https://cloud.mail.ru/public/g1Ay/MPaeCR9FC

Comment: pls provide (simplified if possible) blend file so we can check it out because we cannot "see" any of your settings